# Linq Into Clause Missing Field

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get Citizen's Name_surname also in the output but autocomplete does not bring item.name_surname in the list. Why is that happening? Is that field lost while executing "INTO" clause?

TLDR: I can not retrieve patients name while making temporary result.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LINQ_INTO_CLAUSE
{

public class Citizen
{
    public int id;
    public string name_surname;
}

public class Illness
{
    public int id;
    public string illnessName;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Citizen[] patients = new[]              { new Citizen {id = 123,    name_surname = "John"       },
                                                  new Citizen {id = 2345,   name_surname = "Derek"      },
                                                  new Citizen {id = 345,    name_surname = "Ahmed"      },
                                                  new Citizen {id = 31345,  name_surname = "Mehmed"     }};

        Illness[] illnesses = new[]             { new Illness { id = 123,   illnessName = "Flu"         },
                                                  new Illness { id = 7726,  illnessName = "Flu"         },
                                                  new Illness { id = 123,   illnessName = "Headache"    },
                                                  new Illness { id = 2345,  illnessName = "Kolera"      },
                                                  new Illness { id = 31345, illnessName = "Kolera"      }};


        var _queryResult = from s in patients
                           join k in illnesses on s.id equals k.id
                           into temporaryResult
                           from c in temporaryResult
                           select c;

        foreach (var item in _queryResult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.id+"-"+item.illnessName);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why would you format your code like that? Holy cow

Comment: What is bad about it?

Comment: You have 50 spaces of indentation for some reason. I have to scroll to read it because of that

Comment: I did it because I wanted those object creation part to seem tidier. lol

Comment: Just put the first item on a new line! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store it in an anonymous type, you don't need the `into`:

```
var _queryResult = from p in patients
                   join i in illnesses on p.id equals i.id
                   select new { Patient = p, Illness = i};

foreach (var x in _queryResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Illness.id + "-" + x.Illness.illnessName + " - " + x.Patient.name_surname);
}
```

If you want to use the `into` keyword to get a group of all illnesses of a citizen you can still store it in  an anonymous type. But don't use `from` after `into` which flattens the groups again:

```
var queryResult = from p in patients
                  join i in illnesses on p.id equals i.id
                  into allPatientIllnesses
                  select new
                  {
                      Patient = p,
                      IlnessList = allPatientIllnesses.ToList()
                  };


foreach (var item in queryResult)
{
    Citizen patient = item.Patient;
    string illnesses = string.Join(",", item.IlnessList.Select(i => i.illnessName));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not answering my question. I am asking why name_surname field is not stored in the temporary resultset?

Comment: @Lyrk: Now it's answering it. The `from` after `into` flattens the result to a `Illness` and you can't access the citizen anymore. Look at my edit

Comment: thank you this was really heavy but I understood after looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don;t need the `into...` bit, then you can create a nicer anonymous type with the details you need:

```
var _queryResult = from s in patients
                   join k in illnesses on s.id equals k.id
                   select new
                   {
                       Name = s.name_surname, 
                       Id = k.id, 
                       Illness = k.illnessName 
                   };

foreach (var item in _queryResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name + "-" + item.Id + "-" + item.Illness);
}
```

Comment: Yes that is true but what I wanted to ask is why is that "into" clause cuts the name_surname field from the result? What I mean is I expect name_surname to be stored in temporaryResult resultset also but this is not the case it seems.

Comment: Oh well, sometimes this site is rather strange. Both answers very similar yet I get a downvote and the other gets 3 upvote!

Comment: Yes your answer is the same as upper answer. But you get downvoted lol

Comment: Well Tim's answer is much better now he edited it, I suppose I'll just delete this one.

Comment: No no dont delete it. Your post gave me insight.